# Exception Thrown - Receive data from Arduino to Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, exception, arduino, serial-communication

I'm trying to send serial data from Arduino and read it on Visual Basic. When I execute the code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't: throwing exception, System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Can you help me?
I'm new to Visual Basic, thanks.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
Dim TWSL, TWAL, THL, AoAL, WAL, PeL, RoilL, RyL, RydL As Integer
Dim TWS, TWA, TH, AoA, WA, Pe, Roil, Ry, Ryd, TWSResult, TWAResult, THResult, AoAResult, WAResult, PeResult, RoilResult, RyResult, RydResult As String
Dim StrSerialIn, StrSerialInRam As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.CenterToParent()
    SerialPort1.PortName = "COM4"
    SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
    SerialPort1.Open()
    Timer1.Start()
    SerialPort1.Write(TrackBarAWA.Value & Chr(10))
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        StrSerialIn = SerialPort1.ReadExisting

        Dim TB As New TextBox
        TB.Multiline = True
        TB.Text = StrSerialIn

        If TB.Lines.Count > 0 Then
            If TB.Lines(0) = "Failed to read" Then
                Timer1.Stop()
                SerialPort1.Close()
                Return
            End If

            StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(0).Substring(0, 2)
            If StrSerialInRam = "A" Then
                TWS = TB.Lines(0)
                TWSL = TWS.Length
            Else
                TWS = TWS
            End If

            StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(1).Substring(0, 3)
            If StrSerialInRam = "B" Then
                TWA = TB.Lines(1)
                TWAL = TWA.Length
            Else
                TWA = TWA
            End If

            StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(2).Substring(0, 3)
            If StrSerialInRam = "C" Then
                TH = TB.Lines(2)
                THL = TH.Length
            Else
                TH = TH
            End If

            StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(3).Substring(0, 2)
            If StrSerialInRam = "D" Then
                AoA = TB.Lines(3)
                AoAL = AoA.Length
            Else
                AoA = AoA
            End If

            StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(4).Substring(0, 1)
            If StrSerialInRam = "E" Then
                WA = TB.Lines(4)
                WAL = WA.Length
            Else
                WA = WA
            End If

            StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(5).Substring(0, 3)
            If StrSerialInRam = "F" Then
                Pe = TB.Lines(5)
                PeL = Pe.Length
            Else
                Pe = Pe
            End If

            StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(6).Substring(0, 3)
            If StrSerialInRam = "G" Then
                Roil = TB.Lines(6)
                RoilL = Roil.Length
            Else
                Roil = Roil
            End If

            StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(7).Substring(0, 3)
            If StrSerialInRam = "H" Then
                Ry = TB.Lines(7)
                RyL = Ry.Length
            Else
                Ry = Ry
            End If

            StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(8).Substring(0, 3)
            If StrSerialInRam = "I" Then
                Ryd = TB.Lines(8)
                RydL = Ryd.Length
            Else
                Ryd = Ryd
            End If

            TWSResult = Mid(TWS, 2, TWSL)
            TWAResult = Mid(TWA, 2, TWAL)
            THResult = Mid(TH, 2, THL)
            AoAResult = Mid(AoA, 2, AoAL)
            WAResult = Mid(WA, 2, WAL)
            PeResult = Mid(Pe, 2, PeL)
            RoilResult = Mid(Roil, 2, RoilL)
            RyResult = Mid(Ry, 2, RyL)
            RydResult = Mid(Ryd, 2, RydL)

            TWSvalue.Text = TWSResult
            TWAvalue.Text = TWAResult
            THvalue.Text = THResult
            AoAvalue.Text = AoAResult
            WAvalue.Text = WAResult
            PeValue.Text = PeResult
            RoilValue.Text = RoilResult
            RyValue.Text = RyResult
            RydValue.Text = RydResult
```

Comment: If you have `StrSerialInRam = TB.Lines(0).Substring(0, 2)` (two chars from position 0), how can `StrSerialInRam = "A"`? Maybe you wanted `StrSerialInRam.StartsWith("A")` instead? Are you sure you have enough chars in there? You never test it. -- What make you think that the TexttBox (why a TextBox and not a `List(Of String)`?) contains 9 lines of text? Do you send 8 `0x0A` + `0x0C` to the port? You should test that, too. etc.

Comment: So what does that error message suggest? What happens when you debug it?

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, you are trying to get characters from specific places in specific lines on a text box. Based on the error message you included in your question, I assume the error occurs on a line of code containing the "String. Substring" method. If the string where you are getting the substring from is too short to cover the range you have specified in the substring method, you will get this error. For instance, if you are getting a substring that's 3 characters long from line 2 starting at character 0 and it has less than 3 characters, you will get this error.

See the documentation on the String.Substring method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1)